# Implement mobile touch keypad in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to implement mobile keypad in java script or jquery. I am implement basic structure for keypad But i am not clear about javascript.

```js
$("#phone").find("button").mouseup(function(event){
  var button_pressed = $(event.currentTarget).data("value")
  $("#result").val(t9($("#result").val(),button_pressed))
})

function t9(text,button_pressed){
  // Write your code here
  return text
}
```

```css
#phone button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
}

#phone button span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

#result {
  width: 225px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="phone">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <input type="text" id="result" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button data-value="1" class="key">1
        <span>. , !</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="2" class="key">2
        <span>a b c</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="3" class="key">3
        <span>d e f</span>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button data-value="4" class="key">4
        <span>g h i</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="5" class="key">5
        <span>j k l</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="6" class="key">6
        <span>m n o</span>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button data-value="7" class="key">7
      <span>p q r s</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="8" class="key">8
        <span>t u v</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="9" class="key">9
        <span>w x y z</span>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button data-value="*" class="key">*</button></td>
    <td><button data-value="0" class="key">0</button></td>
    <td><button data-value="#" class="key">#</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: @Rayon. You can run my code. could see when you typing any number and alphabet the it is not showing in input box. But it is should be show in the input box.(touchpad react like mobile keypad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Replace `data('value')` width `attr('data-value')`.
2. return `button_pressed` instead of `text` in `t9` function.
3. Optional - You can replace `$(event.currentTarget)` with `$(this)`

```js
var to = 1000, timeout, counter = 0, lastKey, keyPressTimeout, keyPressTO = 1000;

$("#phone button").bind("mousedown", function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      $result = $('#result'),
      val = $result.val(),
      button_pressed = $this.attr("data-value");

  keyPressTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    // if the click is long add the value of the button to the textxbox
    val += button_pressed;
    $result.val(val);
    keyPressTimeout = null;
  }, keyPressTO);
  
}).bind("mouseup", function(event) {
  clearTimeout(keyPressTimeout);
  
  if (!keyPressTimeout) {
    return false;
  }
  var $this = $(this),
      $result = $('#result'),
      val = $result.val(),
      button_pressed = $this.attr("data-value");

  // if the user clicks on a new key reset all
  if (lastKey !== button_pressed) {
    reset();  
  }

  // if the user click fast on the same key, remove the last charchter to replace it with the new
  if (counter !== 0 && lastKey === button_pressed) {
    val = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
  }

  val += t9(button_pressed);
  $result.val(val);

  // restart the timeout
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  counter++;

  // save the last key pressed so we can compare it in the next click
  lastKey = button_pressed;

  // if the user not clicked on anything within the timeout delay (to variable) reset all.
  timeout = setTimeout(reset, to);
});

function t9(button_pressed) {
  return keys[button_pressed][counter % keys[button_pressed].length];
}

function reset() {
  counter = 0;
  lastKey = null;
}

var keys = {
  '1': ['.', ',', '!'],
  '2': ['a', 'b', 'c']
};
```

```css
#phone button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
}
#phone button span  {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
#result{
  width: 225px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="phone">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <input type="text" id="result" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button data-value="1" class="key">1
        <span>. , !</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="2" class="key">2
        <span>a b c</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="3" class="key">3
        <span>d e f</span>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button data-value="4" class="key">4
        <span>g h i</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="5" class="key">5
        <span>j k l</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="6" class="key">6
        <span>m n o</span>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button data-value="7" class="key">7
      <span>p q r s</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="8" class="key">8
        <span>t u v</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="9" class="key">9
        <span>w x y z</span>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button data-value="*" class="key">*</button></td>
    <td><button data-value="0" class="key">0</button></td>
    <td><button data-value="#" class="key">#</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://output.jsbin.com/seqexi

Comment: I was updated my answer. I did the 2 first keys, you should do the rest.

Comment: thanks for your help. But how to type one and two(digit)(after long press). as per video.

Comment: My pleasure.. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

- Concatenate clicked button value with the existing value in the
  `#result` input
- [`jQuery.data( element )`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/#jQuery-data-element) is added in version `1.4` so use updated version.
- Use `$(this)` to select clicked element than `event.currentTarget` to make it more readable(Depends on developers preference)

```js
$("#phone").find("button").mouseup(function(event) {
  var button_pressed = $(this).data("value");
  $("#result").val(t9($("#result").val(), button_pressed))
})

function t9(text, button_pressed) {
  return text + button_pressed;
}
```

```css
#phone button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
}
#phone button span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
#result {
  width: 225px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="phone">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <input type="text" id="result" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button data-value="1" class="key">1
        <span>. , !</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="2" class="key">2
        <span>a b c</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="3" class="key">3
        <span>d e f</span>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button data-value="4" class="key">4
        <span>g h i</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="5" class="key">5
        <span>j k l</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="6" class="key">6
        <span>m n o</span>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button data-value="7" class="key">7
        <span>p q r s</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="8" class="key">8
        <span>t u v</span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="9" class="key">9
        <span>w x y z</span>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button data-value="*" class="key">*</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="0" class="key">0</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button data-value="#" class="key">#</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```